# My version of phpMyAdmin has lost its 'test' button

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running phpMyAdmin version 4.7.0 on a cloud server. I should be able to configure it as I want it (though I find this difficult).

Until a couple of days ago the 'SQL' window showed a button (near the 'GO' button) that allowed me to run a query in the background without actually generating a table of results (instead I got a one line report saying how many lines were affected). I can't recall the name of the button, but it was descriptive of what it did.

I found this useful. Unfortunately it has disappeared (for no obvious reason) and I can't work out how to get it back. Any answers, please?

Comment: phpMyAdmin version 5.6.30 does not exist.

Comment: You're quite right. How stupid of me to have read the PHP version off the phpMyAdmin page. The version is 4.7.0 THe question still applies!

Answer (score 3):

The button is "Simulate query" but only appears when you are entering a query such as DELETE FROM or UPDATE.

Comment: I have seen it now. It is necessary to type more than just the first word of the query before it appears (e.g. for UPDATE you have to get as far as SET). And it doesn't appear for SELECT, which is understandable but it would sometimes be useful to know how many rows were to be selected (rather than having to see the entire result)

Comment: Indeed the parser waits to be sure about the type of query, so it needs a few words. About SELECT, it's sometimes tricky to obtain the exact row count in advance, especially for InnoDB. By the way, by default you do not see the entire result, just the first 25 rows, and you get the approximate row count.